# Get data after "?" in URL, Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have a URL in the following format.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/event/contract-risk-management/review/

And I need to "parse" the "/event/contract-risk-management/review/" part from it in templates, but I don't know how to get the part after question mark.

I tried **request.path** but it returned only the first part of the URL (without a domain).

What should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, do `request.GET.get('next')` in your `views.py` to get the parameters.

According to Django documentation, in `HttpRequest` objects, `GET` and `POST` attributes are `QueryDict`, which just acts as a dictionary. You can also do normal dictionary lookups like `request.GET['next']` or `request.GET.get('next', None)` on it.

Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects).

Comment: Sure it is in the GET, thanks, any reason no to use "request.GET.next" directly in the template?

Comment: I'm not sure what's your use case, but you shouldn't have too much of the logic in your template, like manipulating urls, doing redirections, etc, those actions should stay in views.py. It also make your web app flow easier to track. When people read your code, they only look at views.py and knows everything, instead of checking view plus templates.